# Failed to Create Data Directory - Google Chrome Cannot Read and Write Its Data Directory - Cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, google-chrome, registry

I've been working on a Cordova app, and I've suddenly had troubles with Chrome.
I've wanted to start debugging, so I added support for a browser platform, and I use Chrome.

After running the app on Chrome, which worked before, I encountered this problem:

> Failed To Create Data Directory
>
> Google Chrome cannot read and write its data directory:
>
> C:/Chromedevsession"
>
> screenshot here: http://prntscr.com/876kax

Things I tried:

- Deleting Chrome -> Reinstalling Chrome - found this online
- Deleting Windows registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` - there's no
  Chrome folder or key inside the Google folder, only an Update folder
- While uninstalled, using a different browser as my default browser - the command that runs the app (cordova run) didn't open another
  browser (I tried Firefox).

It already worked before, and I don't know why it suddenly happened. I tried upgrading to Windows 10 a few times and it failed, so could there be a problem in the registry?

Comment: Might be something to do with permissions. Can you make sure the folder exists in the right location, is writable, and the user has permissions?
(I don't know much about the subject but that's my best guess)

Comment: Which folder? The one in which Google Chrome is installed, its userdata, or my Cordova project folder?

Comment: I meant the folder which is mentioned in the error, 'C:/Chromedevsession'. I have no idea whether it should be there or not, but since Chrome gives you an error that says it cannot read it, just make sure that it *can* and the error would be gone. Just common sense.

Comment: There's no such folder or file.

Comment: I am having the same issue :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by editing the run file (platforms/browser/cordova/run) and removing the speech marks from around C:/Chromedevsession on line 33.

The line now reads:

```
spawn('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', ['--user-data-dir=C:/Chromedevsession', '--disable-web-security', project]);
```

Comment: I was starting the browser using a Python Script.  Removing the quotes (speech marks) also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the script that launches chrome, uses a folder location that typically can't be created with your permissions. That folder is used for history, bookmarks, cookies, etc (ie user data). This is beneficial for testing out features in Chrome (plugins, etc) and not affecting your normal instance. I don't consider it much of a concern here, more of a nuisance message. If you don't like it you could always just manually create that folder on your system as well.

You can see this here what causes the issue

```
switch (process.platform) {
  case 'darwin':
    spawn('open', ['-n', '-a', 'Google\ Chrome', '--args', '--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova_browser', project]);
    break;
  case 'win32':
    //TODO: Use regex to fix location of chrome.exe
    //TODO: Get --user-data-dir to work for windows
    spawn('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', ['--user-data-dir="C:/Chromedevsession"', '--disable-web-security', project]);
    break;
}
```

Since it can't use that folder, I believe it just reverts to the [defaults](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) which on Windows 10 would be

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove Space in Path in Registry Policy

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\UserDataDir
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\UserDataDir
```

Example:

> ${roaming_app_data}\Google\Chrome\User_Data

instead of

> ${roaming_app_data}\Google\Chrome\User Data

Comment: This should not be necessary.  Posting an alternative solution below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution to this.  Just specify the full path to the special directory you want to use for your debug chrome instance.  In my case I set the user data directory to a folder next to the default user data directory, called "Debug".  The following works for me specified as a script in my package.json:

```
"start-remote-debugging-browser": "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe -incognito --app=http://localhost:4200/ --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\mmcin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Debug"
```